# WordPress Potential Vulnerability using Heredoc

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I have a function in a plugin which creates a post programatically. It uses a heredoc to create the html for the post, and I interpolate `plugins_url()` assigned to a variable.

Does this approach create a vulnerability which can be exploited please? If so, how would that work - what would a hacker have to do to exploit it?

I have `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly` at the top of the file.

My function is below:

```
function ra_add_post() {
    $prev_post = get_page_by_title( 'Tile Puzzle',
                    'OBJECT',
                    'post' );

    if ( $prev_post->post_status == false || $prev_post->post_status == 'trash' ):
    $plugins_url     = plugins_url();
    $html        = <<<_HERE
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="board"></div>
</div>

<audio id="audio" src="$plugins_url/tile-puzzle/Success-sound-effect.mp3"></audio>
_HERE;
    endif;

    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'     => 'Tile Puzzle',
    'post_content'   => $html,
    'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );
    wp_insert_post( $new_post );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__,
              'ra_add_post' );
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a problem. Take a look at the [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) docs. It automatically runs the data through [`sanitize_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post/) which is sufficient for sanitizing it.

Also [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/) is just a fancy way to return the proper URL scheme to your plugins (or MU Plugins) folder, it doesn't really do anything dangerous (and if [`plugins_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_url/) *filter* is doing anything bad, you have bigger problems lol)

You'd only really have anything to worry about if you were creating a post with user supplied data, but using `wp_insert_post()` handles 99.9% of all issues you would be running into, even with that.

Using Heredoc doesn't really have much to do with this as well. Heredoc is basically just a syntactic flavor for blocks of HTML. It's really no bigger of a "problem" (or lack-thereof) than using double quoted strings or `sprintf()`.